# SWT toolbar action image 'looks' enabled on focus of editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

Please see the attachment:

[image]

On selecting the editor header, the action is enabled. On changing the focus to some other view or on selecting the rows below, this action is disabled. 
Another point to note is that when there are multiple actions added to the tool bar, only first one looks enabled. Please see:

[image]

I only want the enabling to happen on `Action.setChecked()`.
How can I get rid of this default enabling-disabling behavior?

In the `FormPage`:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.Action;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.IManagedForm;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ScrolledForm;

public class TestEditorPage extends FormPage {

  private Action myAction;

  public TestEditorPage(final TestEditor testEditor) {
    super(testEditor, "1", "MyTitle");
  }

  @Override
  protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) {
    Composite composite = managedForm.getForm().getBody();
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    createTree(composite);
    createActions(managedForm.getForm());
  }

  private Tree createTree(final Composite composite) {
    Tree tree = new Tree(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tree.setLinesVisible(true);
    return tree;
  }

  private void createActions(final ScrolledForm scrolledForm) {
    ImageDescriptor imgDesc =
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER);
    this.myAction = new Action("MyAction", IAction.AS_CHECK_BOX) {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Do some stuff
      }
    };
    this.myAction.setImageDescriptor(imgDesc);
    scrolledForm.getToolBarManager().add(this.myAction);
    scrolledForm.updateToolBar();
  }
}
```

In `FormEditor`

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor;

public class TestEditor extends FormEditor {

  private TestEditorPage page;

  @Override
  protected Composite createPageContainer(final Composite parent) {
    return super.createPageContainer(parent);
  }

  @Override
  protected void addPages() {
    try {
      this.page = new TestEditorPage(this);
      addPage(this.page);
    }
    catch (PartInitException e) {}
  }

  @Override
  public void doSave(final IProgressMonitor monitor) {}

  @Override
  public void doSaveAs() {}
  @Override
  public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Add this editor to the editor extension point: `org.eclipse.ui.editors`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
     <editor
           class="test.treecursor.handlers.TestEditor"
           default="false"
           id="test.treecursor.editor1"
           name="TestEditor">
     </editor>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: By 'enabled' do you mean the light gray box around the icon? That is the focus indicator ('focus ring') and is nothing to do with enablement.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I meant the focus indication. But the focus indicator appears only on the first action (icon) if there are more than one added to the toolbar. Is there a way to not have the focus indication on the icon? The problem is that the user might mistake it for being clicked.

Comment: @greg-449 I did not completely get you. I am adding a FormPage (TestEditorPage in my example above) and adding it to a FormEditor (TestEditor in my example above). Is it possible to change the behavior to not set the focus on the first control of the first page?

Comment: Look at the `setFocus` method of `FormPage` and make sure it is setting the focus to something.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `FormEditor` behaves. Its `setFocus()` either delegates to `setFocus()` of a `IEditPart` associated with the selected tab or to its control. The former case is for non-form multi-page editors, where pages are added as `IEditPart`, and the later is true when adding `IFormPage` (like it is in your code).

It seems impossible to control focus setting in forms, so you can redefine `setFocus()` in your `TestEditor` to direct it to `TestEditorPage` instance. I guess there are multiple ways of doing that, but I can suggest e.g. setting composite's data to this in `TestEditorPage.createFormContent()` and then fetch it in `TestEditor.setFocus()`:

```
public void setFocus() {
    Control control = getControl(getActivePage());
    Object data = control.getData();
    if (data instanceof IEditorPart) {
        ((IEditorPart) data).setFocus();
        return;
    }
    super.setFocus();
}
```

BTW there's a pretty old bug on Eclipse that looks very relevant: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=311916

Stuck with the same problem too, so sharing my solution.